# Illegal characters in path

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Trying to upload a word document then attach it to an email which is sent.

Currently getting an IO exception - Illegal characters in path.

Here's code:

```
try
{
    var fileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/"), ResumeUpload.FileName);

    ResumeUpload.SaveAs(fileName);

    using (var resumeContent = new StreamReader(fileName))
    {
        while (!resumeContent.EndOfStream)
        {
            var emailAttachement = new Attachment(resumeContent.ReadToEnd());
            message.Attachments.Add(emailAttachement);
        }
    }

    var client = new SmtpClient();
    client.Send(message);
}
catch(Exception exception)
{
    // Handle exception...
}
```

Currently, the fileName variable is getting set to:

d:\sites\websitename\website.com.au\home\filename.docx

Any ideas why this would break?

Here's exception

```
Illegal characters in path.   at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path)
  at System.IO.Path.GetFileName(String path)
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
  at System.Net.Mail.AttachmentBase.SetContentFromFile(String fileName, String mediaType)
  at System.Net.Mail.Attachment..ctor(String fileName)
  at JobApplication.JobApplication.SendEmail(StringBuilder emailText)
```

Comment: Does the code fail on ResumeUpload.SaveAs() line?

Comment: that path should be fine, I'm trying to save the file to that path then read from it with the streamreader and attach to email as an attachement. will include exception in question now...

Comment: @Ardman, from what i can tell it's failing when it's trying to instantiate the stream reader?

Comment: Using the filename provided by the user is probably something you should avoid. Someone will upload "index.html"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Attachment(string)` accepts a string of the path. `StreamReader.ReadToEnd` returns the string *contents*. I suspect you simply want:

```
Attachment emailAttachement = new Attachment(filename);
message.Attachments.Add(emailAttachement);
```

Alternatively, use the constructor that accepts a `Stream` and the name/content-type. Note that there are some things to consider if you let people upload arbitrary files into the root of your web-server; I would try to avoid the need to write them to disk (unless you want them for archive), and I wouldn't be writing them to my web-root.

Answer (score 3):

`new Attachment` requires a filename, not content.

Edit: The stacktrace clearly gives that hint away. Use it :)

Comment: I was trying to use the Attachment constructor which accepted a Stream but .ReadToEnd returns a string... Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try attaching with this instead

```
message.Attachments.Add(
    new Attachment(
        new MemoryStream(ResumeUpload.FileBytes), "attachmentName.ext"
        )
    );
```

This will take the bytes uploaded and make a stream with them. The stream should be disposed later.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone's interested, I got it working and this is how it ended up looking:

```
ResumeUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/"), "resumes", ResumeUpload.FileName));

var emailAttachement = new Attachment(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/"), "resumes", ResumeUpload.FileName));
message.Attachments.Add(emailAttachement);

using (var client = new SmtpClient())
{
    client.Send(message);
}
```

Thanks for everyones help :)